# Display CPU usage on Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to measure CPU usage for one of my Azure App Services by going to the "Site Metrics per Instance". The problem is that there is no option to check the CPU usage but CPU time and other stuff like "Average memory working set" and "Data In/Out".

Does someone know how and where I can see the CPU usage for one App Service?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You app is related to an App Service plan : monitoring the plan will give you a percentage, but the app can only be monitored about its own metric : its own CPU time. You can imagine changing the plan for the app then the % would be different. So, on the app itself you can only measure the app CPU time, as % is depending on the plan.

Comment: The plan doesn't show any data at all: https://i.gyazo.com/fbab7098a80cb8238db278dae94fc386.png even though it shows that the 2 apps belong to it.

Comment: This answer is correct. Note that App Service Plan CPU % only makes sense for dedicated plans (Basic or higher). @Muki, if you tried that on a Free/Shared site, that's why you got no data.

Comment: Thanks David, this is a good point. @Muki : all apps related to a service plan share the same resources this is why the % is related to the plan. And to illustrate the difference: you can setup alerts on CPU% for the service plan but setting up alerts on apps, can only be done on CPU usage because, again, % will depend on the plan resource limits.

Comment: @StéphanieHertrich If we know the plan resource limits, how can we convert CPU time (in minutes) to CPU % (as a percentage of available CPU time)? For example, I have a workbook chart that just shows a line varying between 0s and 500ms on the y-axis (and a total of "26 seconds") of CPU time in a 60 minute window, but it's unclear how to convert that data into a meaningful chart. e.g. what does "25ms of CPU time" even mean? CPU scheduling quanta are much smaller than that... why is it even a line-chart and not a histogram? argh

Answer (score 0):

On the old/classic portal, you can see the CPU metric by selecting you service and "Monitor": isn't this the CPU usage that you are looking for ?
[image]

Comment: Hey! That is the CPU Time, I would like to see the CPU Usage (%). It's not really the same thing unless I'm wrong about it?

Answer (score 0):

Just go to App's Metrics > In resource panel select your App Plan related to your App > Now In Metrics panel you will get "CPU PERCENTAGE" Option.